# Property mysteriously set to nil behind my back

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a property on a class that is being set to nil, and I have no clue what's doing it.  I've set a symbolic breakpoint on it (watchpoint) and that's not catching it, and I've set the typical breakpoint in the setter as well, and that's not catching it.

What is the purpose of the `activeTextField` property?
When the user starts entering data in a field, if that field will be blocked by the keyboard being shown, I slide the screen up enough to show the field.

So something is happening between the point of `textFieldDidBeginEditing` setting the value, and the keyboard being shown, which are literally one right after the other, and every time, in `keyboardWasShown`, my `activeTextField` = nil.

How can I find out why this is being set to nil?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *activeTextField;

-(void)setActiveTextField:(UITextField *)activeTextField
    {
        _activeTextField = activeTextField;
    }


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        self.activeTextField = textField;
    }



-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        self.activeTextField = nil;
    }



-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        if (self.activeTextField == nil)
            {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that textFieldDidEndEditing is not being called?

Comment: Have you confirmed that keybaordWasShown and textFieldDidBeginEditing are being executed on the same thread?

Comment: NSLog on textFieldDidEndEditing see if that's get called. Pretty sure it is that one.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb programmer error.  I had 2 classes that inherit from the code I posted above, and they have nearly identical names and one was registered for keyboard notifications and the other was not, which made my results so confusing.

Comment: I'm on the edge of my seat...!